# Find the default branch name for a Git repository?

Tags: git, branch

I would like to be able to ask Git "what is the default branch name for this repository?" and I would expect either `main` or `master` as the result. I've search `git config` but haven't been able to find a/the relevant option.

Comment: if the repo existed before July of 2020 it is almost certainly 'master', but if your config has the setting `init.defaultBranch` that should indicate the default branch name. you could also look through `.git/refs/remotes/origin/` to see if there is a ref for main|master if you are sure its one of those.

Comment: it doesn't need to be main OR master.. it can be anything.  the org I just started at calls the master branch `dev`.  clear your branches and look at the file @FrankThomas mentions.

Comment: Is it a purely local repository, or is it cloned from a remote? The remote repo *will* have a "default checkout after cloning" branch which can be queried, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

This simple snippet should work:

```
git remote show origin | sed -n '/HEAD branch/s/.*: //p'
```

Replace origin with name of your remote if it's not default